# How to run powershell script in runbook based on clientid and client secret

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-runbook

Currently I am using username and password to connect SPO Service uisng below code :

```
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($UserName, $Password)
Connect-SPOService -Url "https://$OrganizationName-admin.sharepoint.com" -Credential $psCred
```

Now i want to use ClientId and client secret of my App and remove username and password. I have given Global Administrator roles for my app also. So based on my application ClientId and clientsecret i want to execute my PowerShell scripts now. Can someone help me on this.

Comment: Please check if this is helpful : https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/03/connect-pnponline-with-appid-and-appsecret.html

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT Thanks for the reply but its worked for only sharepoint related is there any way currently i am using below command and i want removed dependancy of username and password :  $psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($UserName, $Password)

Comment: AFAIK, SPO is only for user with Sharepoint Admin or global admin access so it uses MFA for authentication to the sharepoint url. whereas PnP allows it to use any form of authentication which can be fount here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/connect-pnponline?view=sharepoint-ps

Answer (score 0):

As @[AnsumanBal-MT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15969299/ansumanbal-mt) suggested  posting it as an answer to help other community members .

"

- SPO is only for user with Sharepoint **Admin or global admin** access so it uses MFA for authentication to the `sharepoint url`.
- Instead of that we can use PnP which allow us to use any form of authentication .We can't use client id in SPO .

Based on the [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/connect-pnponline?view=sharepoint-ps) For example:

```
   Connect-PnPOnline
           [-ReturnConnection]
           [-Url] <String>
           [-Credentials <CredentialPipeBind>]
           [-CurrentCredentials]
           [-CreateDrive]
           [-DriveName <String>]
           [-ClientId <String>]
           [-RedirectUri <String>]
           [-AzureEnvironment <AzureEnvironment>]
           [-TenantAdminUrl <String>]
           [-TransformationOnPrem]
           [<CommonParameters>]
```

For more information please refer this MS DOC:  [Granting access using SharePoint App-Only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs)